# Rails 3 join table article_categories only allow one category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering how to build a join table articles_categories, but one where there can only be one category per article. I know the typical way to do categories is to allow multiple categories for each article with has_and_belongs_to_many, but I'd like only allow one category per article. I have already set up my articles_categories join table with the has_and_belongs_to_many associations. I followed an example from Apress Beginning Rails 3, that also recommended to set the articles_categories table :id => false. Will I also have to update the table to have an id? Thanks!

So far I have updated my articles model to has_one :category and the category model to has_many :articles, but I get an error while testing in irb:

```
a = Article.first
a.category
```

The error is:

```
Category Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."article_id" = 1500 LIMIT 1
PG::Error: ERROR:  column categories.article_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories"  WHERE "categories"...
```

Can somebody tell me how to better set this up? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want each article has only one category you should not use cross table. Simply use references in migration — http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#highlighter_472212

```
rails g migration ArticleHasCategory category:references
```

Then you specify the article has category in model

```
belongs_to :category
```

When you call `article.category`. It will automatically look for column `<relation name>_id` which should point to record in `<relation name>`

Answer (score 4):

The `Article` model should have a `belongs_to :category` association instead of `has_one :category`. Also don't forget to add a `category_id` column to `articles` table (You can add a migration for that If you haven't already).